# Ebean MetaQueryStatistic results in table name null

Tags: playframework, ebean

I tried to use (according to http://www.avaje.org/metatopqueries.html)

```
List<MetaQueryStatistic> list = Ebean.find(MetaQueryStatistic.class).findList();
```

to get my query stats but I got

```
[error] Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT T0.AUTOFETCH_TUNED C0, T0.BEAN_TYPE C1, T0.ORIG_QUERY_PLAN_HASH C2, T0.FINAL_QUERY_PLAN_HASH C3, T0.SQL C4, T0.EXECUTION_COUNT C5, T0.TOTAL_LOADED_BEANS C6, T0.TOTAL_TIME_MICROS C7, T0.COLLECTION_START C8, T0.LAST_QUERY_TIME C9, T0.AVG_TIME_MICROS C10, T0.AVG_LOADED_BEANS C11 
[error] FROM NULL[*] T0 "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
[error] select t0.autofetch_tuned c0, t0.bean_type c1, t0.orig_query_plan_hash c2, t0.final_query_plan_hash c3, t0.sql c4, t0.execution_count c5, t0.total_loaded_beans c6, t0.total_time_micros c7, t0.collection_start c8, t0.last_query_time c9, t0.avg_time_micros c10, t0.avg_loaded_beans c11 
[error] from null t0 [42001-168]
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:194)
```

Notice the table name is NULL which I think is why it fails. If you take a look at the class, you'll see it doesn't have the `@Table` annotation. I'm not sure if that's an issue or some configuration is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ebean/Statistic/ebean/3wOPQIbBuvs/f8dVZtxP54EJ

Heads up - com.avaje.ebean.meta.MetaQueryStatistic is getting replaced, new API for getting query execution statistics
...

Comment: The ebean version I'm using is 3.1.1 which still has the MetaQueryStatistic class but doesn't seem to have those new APIs.